# Simple File I/O and searching using batch

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to do a simple bit of file I/O in batch. It's been a while since I've done batch and even then I always screwed up loops in batch anyway.

Regardless, I've to an external file that is just a list of pairs of strings, separated by a space. I need to have the script read the file, pull out the strings and use each pair as a part of the arguments into another program. I've got this second part down but I need to read the file.

Simpler:

external file file.txt has the following stuff:

```
STRING1 STRING2
STRING3 STRING4
...
STRINGN STRINGN+1
```

Script just needs to do this

```
:Run program with STRING1 and STRING2
:Run program with STRING3 and STRING4
...
```

Comment: [for /f as described here](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) is your command. Should be easy to follow, but if you're stuck do post where your problem is

Answer (score 3):

Read `HELP FOR` and then try at the command line

```
for /f "tokens=1,2" %a in (file.txt) do @echo :Run program with %a and %b >>script.bat
```